# Returning the category name

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

an easy one for you woocommerce people.

I have customised the content-single-product.php page quite heavily, and the last thing I need is to have the category that the product belongs to as the page title.

What do I need to 'echo?!?!' the category?

Any help or a pointer in the right direction would be magnificent.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woocommerce categories are a custom taxonomy in Wordpress. You can retrieve an array with all the terms associated with a post using the `get_terms()` function.

In your case the taxonomy is called `product_cat`, so you have to call the function with those parameters:

> $terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat');

Now in $terms you have all the categories the post belongs to.
If you want to print just one them, say the first, you can do that in this way:

> echo $terms[0]->name;